# script on changing directory ownership via bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to find directories older than 150 days and change their ownership as root. Please can you advice on how do i fix the below pls?

`find /mnt/mailfolder/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +150 -printf "%P\n" -exec "chown -R oracle:oinstall {}"`

Comment: What exactly is now working? Do you get any error, or any undesired behaviour?

Comment: find: missing argument to `-exec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of `find` is a bit tricky, especially with `-exec`.
Try:

```
 find /mnt/mailfolder/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +150 -printf "%P\n" -exec chown -R oracle:oinstall "{}" \;
```

Comment: many many thanks. ive understood what needs doing. much appreciated